# Accuracy of my DL model remains constant. It's not increasing

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I've trained a DL model for SVHN dataset

I followed this [tutorial](https://jovian.ml/pratham-10/course-project/v/6?utm_source=embed)

My code:

```
import torch
from torchvision.datasets import SVHN
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
from torch.utils.data.dataloader import DataLoader
import svhn_class as S
import asyncio
import svhn_func as SF
import loss_accuracy as LA

test_ds=SVHN(root="E:/git/Door_number_finding_system/data",split='test', download=True, transform=ToTensor())
train_ds=SVHN(root="E:/git/Door_number_finding_system/data", download=True, transform=ToTensor())


batch_size=128
train_loader=DataLoader(train_ds,batch_size,shuffle=True,num_workers=4,pin_memory=True)
test_loader=DataLoader(test_ds,batch_size,num_workers=4,pin_memory=True)

input_size = 3072
num_classes = 10   

model = S.SvhnModel(input_size, out_size=num_classes)

if __name__=='__main__':
    torch.multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    SF.loadModel(train_loader,model)
    history=[]
    history = asyncio.run(SF.model_val(train_loader,test_loader,model))
    for xb, yb in test_loader:
        print('yb:', yb)
        break
    LA.loss(history)
    LA._accuracy(history)
```

In svhn_func.py

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

def loadModel(train_loader,model):
    for images, labels in train_loader:
        outputs = model(images)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(outputs, torch.LongTensor(labels))
        
    print('outputs.shape : ', outputs.shape)
    print('Sample outputs :\n', outputs.data)

def accuracy(outputs, labels):
    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)
    return torch.tensor(torch.sum(preds == labels).item() / len(preds))

def evaluate(model, test_loader):
    outputs = [model.validation_step(batch) for batch in test_loader]
    return model.validation_epoch_end(outputs)

def fit (epochs, lr, model, train_loader, val_loader, opt_func=torch.optim.SGD) :
    _history = []
    optimizer = opt_func(model.parameters(), lr)
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for batch in train_loader:
            loss = model.training_step(batch)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
        result = evaluate(model, val_loader)
        model.epoch_end(epoch, result)
        _history.append(result)
    return _history

async def model_val(train_loader,test_loader,model):
    history = [evaluate(model, test_loader)]
    print("epoches : 1e-2")
    history += fit(10,1e-4, model, train_loader, test_loader)
    print("epoches : 1e-3")
    history += fit(10,1e-5, model, train_loader, test_loader)
    return history
```

In svhn_class.py

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np
from torchvision.datasets import SVHN
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
from torchvision.utils import make_grid
from torch.utils.data.dataloader import DataLoader
import svhn_func as SF

class SvhnModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_size, out_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(in_size, 1024)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(1024, 512)
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(512, 256)
        self.linear4 = nn.Linear(256, 128)
        self.linear5 = nn.Linear(128, 64)
        self.linear6 = nn.Linear(64, 32)
        self.linear7 = nn.Linear(32, out_size)
        
    def forward(self, xb):
        xb = xb.view(xb.size(0),-1)
        if xb.shape[1]==3072:
            out = self.linear1(xb)
            out = F.relu(out)
            xb=out
        out = self.linear2(xb)
        out = F.relu(out)
        out = self.linear3(out)
        out = F.relu(out)
        out = self.linear4(out)
        out = F.relu(out)
        out = self.linear5(out)
        out = F.relu(out)
        out = self.linear6(out)
        out = F.relu(out)
        out = self.linear7(out)
        return out
        
    def training_step(self, batch):
        images, labels = batch 
        out = self(images)                  # Generate predictions 
        loss = F.cross_entropy(out, labels) # Calculate loss
        return loss
    
    def validation_step(self, batch):
        images, labels = batch 
        out = self(images)                  # Generate predictions
        loss = F.cross_entropy(out, labels)   # Calculate loss
        acc = SF.accuracy(out, labels)           # Calculate accuracy
        return {'val_loss': loss, 'val_acc': acc}
        
    def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs):
        batch_losses = [x['val_loss'] for x in outputs]
        epoch_loss = torch.stack(batch_losses).mean()   # Combine losses
        batch_accs = [x['val_acc'] for x in outputs]
        epoch_acc = torch.stack(batch_accs).mean()      # Combine accuracies
        return {'val_loss': epoch_loss.item(), 'val_acc': epoch_acc.item()}
    
    def epoch_end(self, epoch, result):
        print("Epoch [{}], val_loss: {:.4f}, val_acc: {:.4f}".format(epoch, result['val_loss'], result['val_acc']))
```

loss_accuracy.py

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def loss(history):
    losses = [x['val_loss'] for x in history]
    print("Losses : ",losses)
    plt.plot(losses, '-x')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    plt.title('Loss vs. No. of epochs')
    plt.show()

def _accuracy(history):
    accuracies = [x['val_acc'] for x in history]
    print("Accuracies : ",accuracies)
    plt.plot(accuracies, '-x')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.ylabel('accuracy')
    plt.title('Accuracy vs. No. of epochs')
    plt.show()
```

I did everything given in the tutorial, yet my output is :

```
Epoch [0], val_loss: 2.2832, val_acc: 0.0969
Epoch [1], val_loss: 2.2823, val_acc: 0.0969
Epoch [2], val_loss: 2.2822, val_acc: 0.0969
Epoch [3], val_loss: 2.2821, val_acc: 0.0969
Epoch [4], val_loss: 2.2821, val_acc: 0.0969
Epoch [5], val_loss: 2.2820, val_acc: 0.0969
Epoch [6], val_loss: 2.2819, val_acc: 0.0969
Epoch [7], val_loss: 2.2819, val_acc: 0.0969
Epoch [8], val_loss: 2.2818, val_acc: 0.0969
Epoch [9], val_loss: 2.2818, val_acc: 0.0969
```

Instead of

```
Epoch [0], val_loss: 1.3448, val_acc: 0.6588
Epoch [1], val_loss: 1.0892, val_acc: 0.7248
Epoch [2], val_loss: 1.3739, val_acc: 0.6748
Epoch [3], val_loss: 0.6882, val_acc: 0.8057
Epoch [4], val_loss: 1.1592, val_acc: 0.7173
Epoch [5], val_loss: 0.7198, val_acc: 0.8027
Epoch [6], val_loss: 0.6922, val_acc: 0.8137
Epoch [7], val_loss: 0.7197, val_acc: 0.8120
Epoch [8], val_loss: 0.7039, val_acc: 0.8042
Epoch [9], val_loss: 0.6572, val_acc: 0.8281
```

as given in that tutorial

The accuracy remains constant. It's not increasing. Even the loss is not decreasing drastically.

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT :

Before down voting this question, it would be nice if you mention the reason for down voting

Comment: You seem to be missing a softmax activation at the output of your model.